# Comma in return value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I know the desired syntax lies in the first function but I for the life of me can't find where it is.

I've attempted to remove commas and add spaces to each `.split()` each has yielded an undesired return value.

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    price_list = prices.split(',')  
    results = ''
    for price in price_list:  
        results += price.split('$')[0]   
    return results

def main():
    prices = "US$40, AU$89, JP$200"
    price_result = get_country_codes(prices)
    print(price_result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The current output:

```
US AU JP
```

The desired output:

```
US, AU, JP
```

Comment: please fix the code indentations, as the code example can not be run like this.

Comment: Also, are you using Python 2 or 3? Don't just link both tags without a good reason to do so. There is also just the `Python` tag if the version does not matter

Comment: Thanks for formatting your code after being asked to do so; not many users do so.

Comment: `price_result = re.sub('\$\d+', '', prices)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could benefit from using a list to collect the country codes of the prices instead of a string. Then you can use `', '.join()` later.

Maybe like this:

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    country_code_list = []

    for price in prices.split(','):
        country_code = price.split('$')[0].strip()
        country_code_list.append(country_code)

    return country_code_list

if __name__ == '__main__':
    prices = "US$40, AU$89, JP$200"
    result_list = get_country_codes(prices)
    print(', '.join(result_list))
```

Or if you like really short code:

```
prices = "US$40, AU$89, JP$200"
print(
    ', '.join(
        price.split('$')[0].strip()
        for price in prices.split(',')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use regex if you want to. Since you know country codes will be two capital letters only (A-Z), you can look for a match of two capital letters that precede a dollar sign.

```
def get_country_codes(prices):
    country_codes = re.findall(r'([A-Z]{2})\$', prices)
    return ', '.join(country_codes)
```

See [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/vY9eY5/88).

Answer (score 0):

Look at the successive steps:

Your string:

```
In [1]: prices = "US$40, AU$89, JP$200"
```

split into a list on comma

```
In [2]: alist = prices.split(',')                                                    
In [3]: alist                                                                        
Out[3]: ['US$40', ' AU$89', ' JP$200']
```

split the substrings on $

```
In [4]: [price.split('$') for price in alist]                                        
Out[4]: [['US', '40'], [' AU', '89'], [' JP', '200']]
```

select the first element:

```
In [5]: [price.split('$')[0] for price in alist]                                     
Out[5]: ['US', ' AU', ' JP']
```

Your `+=` joins the strings as is; same as `join` with ''.  Note that the substrings still have the initial blank for the original string.

```
In [6]: ''.join([price.split('$')[0] for price in alist])                            
Out[6]: 'US AU JP'
```

Join with comma:

```
In [7]: ','.join([price.split('$')[0] for price in alist])                           
Out[7]: 'US, AU, JP'
```

`join` is the easiest way of joining a list of strings with a specific delimiter between, in effect reversing a `split`.  `+=` in a loop is harder to use, since it tends to add an extra delimiter at the start or end.